# Transforming XML so that all its elements and attributes effectively become "minOccurs 1"

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5

I would like to transform a complex XML element so that its structure becomes "regular" - all subelements and attributes present in this element anywhere will be present in 100% of its nodes.

It's probably easier to show what I mean...

**Sample input:**

```
<product>

    <size name="S"/>            

    <size>
        <stock>10</stock>
    </size>

</product>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<product>

    <size name="S">    
        <stock/>
    </size>

    <size name="">
        <stock>10</stock>
    </size>

</product>
```

**What happened:**

The first `size` element was supplied with an empty subelement `stock` (because the second `size` element had one).

Attribute `/size@name` with an empty value was added to the second `size` subelement (because the first `size` element had one).

**Preconditions:**

- Processed XML is unlikely to be big (no problem with using LINQ, caching all of it in memory etc.)
- I don't know its XML schema in advance.

Comment: Where is the malformed XML coming from?  Can you change the way it is built?  Just trying to get a better picture of your scenario.

Comment: I have not actually attempted to code any solution, my thought is to iterate recursively over the document and to create some sort of a dictionary, where we would store - for each element we come across - all of its subelements and attributes, even if they only occured once. After that I'd iterate over the document again. It's doable, it just feels "quick and dirty". I wondered if there are some smarter tricks (I know about XSLT transformations but never used it and I don't even know if they're applicable here).

Comment: @DJ Quimby - it's not malformed as such. It is an XML containing commercial offer; products and their data. Application user defines what-is-what (which element or attribute contains what type of data), and then the application converts it into a known offer format. The XML is flattened into a datatable in the process. Due to the way the conversion modul works, I need to insert empty values as placeholders. Otherwise the stock quantity from size #2 will end up as stock quantity for size #1 etc.

Comment: @Morawski If I was faced with the same issue, I would do exactly as you stated in your comment.  Comb through the entire document and build up an index of all existing nodes.  Then iterate back through and insert any missing nodes to create a uniform document.  There could be some tool out there to "unflatten" the XML so to speak but a quick Google search didn't provide any answers.  Good luck on this.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should match your expectations.

Using this **test.xml** file as input

```
 <product xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/v0.1">

    <size name="S"/>

    <size>
      <stock>
        <a.el a.att="a.value"/>
      </stock>
    </size>

    <size>
      <stock>
        10
        <b.el b.att="b.value"/>
      </stock>
    </size>

    <size size.att="size.value" name="e">
      <stock>
        12
        <b.el b.att2="b.value2"/>
      </stock>
    </size>

  </product>
```

This generates the following **valid and normalized** output

```
<product xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/v0.1">
  <size name="S" size.att="">
    <stock>
      <a.el a.att=""></a.el>
      <b.el b.att="" b.att2=""></b.el>
    </stock>
  </size>
  <size name="" size.att="">
    <stock>
      <a.el a.att="a.value" />
      <b.el b.att="" b.att2=""></b.el>
    </stock>
  </size>
  <size name="" size.att="">
    <stock>
        10
        <b.el b.att="b.value" b.att2="" /><a.el a.att=""></a.el></stock>
  </size>
  <size size.att="size.value" name="e">
    <stock>
        12
        <b.el b.att2="b.value2" b.att="" /><a.el a.att=""></a.el></stock>
  </size>
</product>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
            XNamespace ns = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;

            var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            mgr.AddNamespace("ns", ns.ToString());

            var elements = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/ns:product/ns:size", mgr);

            Descriptor desc = Descriptor.InferFrom(elements);

            desc.Normalize(elements);
            Console.Write(xDoc.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Descriptor
    {
        private readonly IList<XName> _attributeNames = new List<XName>();
        private readonly IDictionary<XName, Descriptor> _elementDescriptors = new Dictionary<XName, Descriptor>();

        public XName Name { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<XName> AttributeNames { get { return _attributeNames; } }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<XName, Descriptor>> ElementDescriptors { get { return _elementDescriptors;  } }

        private void UpdateNameFrom(XElement element)
        {
            if (Name == null)
            {
                Name = element.Name;
                return;
            }

            if (element.Name == Name)
                return;

            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        private void Add(XAttribute att)
        {
            XName name = att.Name;
            if (_attributeNames.Contains(name))
                return;

            _attributeNames.Add(name);
        }

        public static Descriptor InferFrom(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
        {
            var desc = new Descriptor();

            foreach (var element in elements)
                InferFromInternal(element, desc);

            return desc;
        }

        private static void InferFromInternal(XElement element, Descriptor desc)
        {
            desc.UpdateNameFrom(element);

            foreach (var att in element.Attributes())
                desc.Add(att);

            foreach (var subElement in element.Elements())
                desc.Add(subElement);
        }

        private void Add(XElement subElement)
        {
            Descriptor desc;
            if (_elementDescriptors.ContainsKey(subElement.Name))
                desc = _elementDescriptors[subElement.Name];
            else
            {
                desc = new Descriptor();
                _elementDescriptors.Add(subElement.Name, desc);
            }

            InferFromInternal(subElement, desc);
        }

        public void Normalize(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
        {
            foreach (var element in elements)
                NormalizeInternal(element);
        }

        private void NormalizeInternal(XElement element)
        {
            if (element.Name != Name)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            foreach (var attribute in AttributeNames)
            {
                var att = element.Attribute(attribute);

                if (att != null)
                    continue;

                element.Add(new XAttribute(attribute, string.Empty));
            }

            foreach (var attribute in _elementDescriptors)
            {
                XElement el = element.Element(attribute.Key);

                if (el == null)
                {
                    el = new XElement(attribute.Key, string.Empty);
                    element.Add(el);
                }

                attribute.Value.NormalizeInternal(el);
            }
        }
    }
}
```